# Google map API 3 street view panorama by photographer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I create a street view Panorama by the following code, but it returns a custom street view which was taken by some photographers. Is there any method to ignore those panoramas as some of them are internal building views, I just want to get the google official street view?

```
pano.setOptions({
    visible: true,
    position: map.getCenter(),                  
    enableCloseButton : false
});
```

Comment: Set the source to outdoor.